# Cell formatting issue in dynamic table created with OpenXml 2.7 Wordprocessing

Tags: openxml-sdk, openxml-table

First I have created table manually using MS Word 2010. And then I inspected that table using Open Xml Productivity tool and used the reflected code to generate dynamic table with same cell formattings using C#.

But when the Table is generated, there is a white space at the bottom of every cell.

[image]

After increased the row height using MS Word 2010

[image]

And I even tried the basic example here [Add tables to word processing documents (Open XML SDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-add-tables-to-word-processing-documents). but the same result. Any solution to get rid of this white line ?

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code. I think only for the first column its is adding.

MSDN examples are not adding any white space at the bottom of every cell.

try to copy paste the below code in your solution. This is msdn example

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using DW = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing;
using PIC = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures;

namespace word
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            // CreateWordprocessingDocument(@"D:\data\word.docx");
            //string document = @"D:\data\pic1.docx";
            //string fileName = @"D:\data\Capture.JPG";
            //InsertAPicture(document, fileName);
            string fileName = @"D:\data\Table7.docx";
            CreateTable2(fileName);
        }
        public static void CreateTable2(string fileName)

        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
               WordprocessingDocument.Create(fileName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {

                MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

                mainPart.Document = new Document();
                Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
                body.AppendChild(para1("4.1 Process"));
                // Create a table.
                Table tbl = new Table();
                tbl.AppendChild(tablestyle());

                // Add 3 columns to the table.
                TableGrid tg = new TableGrid(new GridColumn(), new GridColumn(), new GridColumn(), new GridColumn(), new GridColumn());
                tbl.AppendChild(tg);
                // Add row to the table.
                tbl.AppendChild(templaterow());
                string[] items = { "Mike Gold", "Don Box",
                        "Sundar Lal", "Neel Beniwal","123" };
                List<string> authorsRange = new List<string>(items);
                tbl.AppendChild(rowcolumns(authorsRange));


                body.AppendChild(tbl);


            }
        }
        public static void CreateTable1(string fileName)

        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
               WordprocessingDocument.Create(fileName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {

                wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
                // siga a ordem
                Document doc = new Document();
                Body body = new Body();

                // 1 paragrafo
                Paragraph para = new Paragraph();

                ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
                ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Normal" };
                Justification justification1 = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Left };
                ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties1 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();

                paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);
                paragraphProperties1.Append(justification1);
                paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties1);

                Run run = new Run();
                RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();

                Text text = new Text() { Text = "4. Process Details" };

                // siga a ordem 
                run.Append(runProperties1);
                run.Append(text);
                para.Append(paragraphProperties1);
                para.Append(run);

                // 2 paragrafo
                Paragraph para2 = new Paragraph();

                ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties2 = new ParagraphProperties();
                ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId2 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Heading1" };
                Justification justification2 = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Start };
                ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties2 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();

                paragraphProperties2.Append(paragraphStyleId2);
                paragraphProperties2.Append(justification2);
                paragraphProperties2.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties2);

                Run run2 = new Run();
                Text text2 = new Text() { Text = "4.1 Process Maps" };
                //text2.Text = "4.1 Process Maps";

                run2.AppendChild(text2);

                para2.Append(paragraphProperties2);
                para2.Append(run2);


                //Para2

                Paragraph para3 = new Paragraph();

                ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties3 = new ParagraphProperties();
                ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId3 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Heading2" };
                Justification justification3 = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Start };
                ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties3 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();

                paragraphProperties3.Append(paragraphStyleId3);
                paragraphProperties3.Append(justification3);
                paragraphProperties3.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties3);


                Run run3 = new Run();
                Text text3 = new Text() { Text = "4.2 Process Steps" };
                //Text text3 = new Text();
                //text3.Text = "4.2 Process Steps";

                run3.AppendChild(text3);

                para3.Append(paragraphProperties3);
                para3.Append(run3);
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                // Create a table.
                Table tbl = new Table();

                // Set the style and width for the table.
                TableProperties tableProp = new TableProperties();
                TableStyle tableStyle = new TableStyle() { Val = "TableGrid" };

                // Make the table width 100% of the page width.
                TableWidth tableWidth = new TableWidth() { Width = "5000", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Pct };

                //// Create Table Borders

                TableBorders tblBorders = new TableBorders();



                TopBorder topBorder = new TopBorder();

                topBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Thick);

                topBorder.Color = "CC0000";

                tblBorders.AppendChild(topBorder);



                BottomBorder bottomBorder = new BottomBorder();

                bottomBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Thick);

                bottomBorder.Color = "CC0000";

                tblBorders.AppendChild(bottomBorder);



                RightBorder rightBorder = new RightBorder();

                rightBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Thick);

                rightBorder.Color = "CC0000";

                tblBorders.AppendChild(rightBorder);



                LeftBorder leftBorder = new LeftBorder();

                leftBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Thick);

                leftBorder.Color = "CC0000";

                tblBorders.AppendChild(leftBorder);



                InsideHorizontalBorder insideHBorder = new InsideHorizontalBorder();

                insideHBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Thick);

                insideHBorder.Color = "CC0000";

                tblBorders.AppendChild(insideHBorder);



                InsideVerticalBorder insideVBorder = new InsideVerticalBorder();

                insideVBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Thick);

                insideVBorder.Color = "CC0000";

                tblBorders.AppendChild(insideVBorder);



                //// Add the table borders to the properties

                tableProp.AppendChild(tblBorders);

                // Apply
                tableProp.Append(tableStyle, tableWidth);
                tbl.AppendChild(tableProp);

                // Add 3 columns to the table.
                TableGrid tg = new TableGrid(new GridColumn(), new GridColumn(), new GridColumn(), new GridColumn(), new GridColumn());
                tbl.AppendChild(tg);

                // Create 1 row to the table.
                TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();



                // Add a cell to each column in the row.
                TableCell tc1 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Step"))));
                TableCell tc2 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("SubStep"))));
                TableCell tc3 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Group"))));
                TableCell tc4 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Description"))));
                TableCell tc5 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("ScreenShot"))));
                tr1.Append(tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4, tc5);

                // Add row to the table.
                tbl.AppendChild(tr1);

                // Add the table to the document


                body.Append(para);
                body.Append(para2);
                body.Append(para3);
                body.AppendChild(tbl);

                doc.Append(body);

                wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document = doc;
                wordDocument.Save();

                wordDocument.Close();

            }

        }



        public static void CreateTable(string fileName)
        {
            // Use the file name and path passed in as an argument 
            // to open an existing Word 2007 document.
            // Create a document by supplying the filepath.
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
                WordprocessingDocument.Create(fileName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                // Add a main document part. 
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

                // Create the document structure and add some text.
                mainPart.Document = new Document();
                Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
                // Create an empty table.
                Table table = new Table();

                // Create a TableProperties object and specify its border information.
                TableProperties tblProp = new TableProperties(
                    new TableBorders(
                        new TopBorder()
                        {
                            Val =
                            new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Dashed),
                            Size = 24
                        },
                        new BottomBorder()
                        {
                            Val =
                            new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Dashed),
                            Size = 24
                        },
                        new LeftBorder()
                        {
                            Val =
                            new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Dashed),
                            Size = 24
                        },
                        new RightBorder()
                        {
                            Val =
                            new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Dashed),
                            Size = 24
                        },
                        new InsideHorizontalBorder()
                        {
                            Val =
                            new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Dashed),
                            Size = 24
                        },
                        new InsideVerticalBorder()
                        {
                            Val =
                            new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Dashed),
                            Size = 24
                        }
                    )
                );

                // Append the TableProperties object to the empty table.
                table.AppendChild<TableProperties>(tblProp);

                // Create a row.
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();

                // Create a cell.
                TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();

                // Specify the width property of the table cell.
                tc1.Append(new TableCellProperties(
                    new TableCellWidth() { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width = "2400" }));

                // Specify the table cell content.
                tc1.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("some text"))));

                // Append the table cell to the table row.
                tr.Append(tc1);

                // Create a second table cell by copying the OuterXml value of the first table cell.
                TableCell tc2 = new TableCell(tc1.OuterXml);

                // Append the table cell to the table row.
                tr.Append(tc2);

                // Append the table row to the table.
                table.Append(tr);

                // Append the table to the document.
                //doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(table);
                body.Append(table);
            }
        }

        public static void CreateWordprocessingDocument(string filepath)
        {
            // Create a document by supplying the filepath.
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
                WordprocessingDocument.Create(filepath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                // Add a main document part. 
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

                // Create the document structure and add some text.
                mainPart.Document = new Document();
                Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
                body.AppendChild(paragraph("12345"));

            }
        }

        public static Paragraph para1(string txt)
        {


            // 1 paragrafo
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();

            ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
            ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Normal" };
            Justification justification1 = new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Left };
            ParagraphMarkRunProperties paragraphMarkRunProperties1 = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();

            paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);
            paragraphProperties1.Append(justification1);
            paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphMarkRunProperties1);

            Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
            run.AppendChild(new Text(txt));

            //para.Append(paragraphProperties1);
            //para.Append(run);
            return para;
        }


        public static TableProperties tablestyle()
        {
            // Set the style and width for the table.
            TableProperties tableProp = new TableProperties();
            TableStyle tableStyle = new TableStyle() { Val = "TableGrid" };

            // Make the table width 100% of the page width.
            TableWidth tableWidth = new TableWidth() { Width = "5000", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Pct };

            //// Create Table Borders

            TableBorders tblBorders = new TableBorders();



            TopBorder topBorder = new TopBorder();

            topBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Thick);

            topBorder.Color = "CC0000";

            tblBorders.AppendChild(topBorder);



            BottomBorder bottomBorder = new BottomBorder();

            bottomBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Thick);

            bottomBorder.Color = "CC0000";

            tblBorders.AppendChild(bottomBorder);



            RightBorder rightBorder = new RightBorder();

            rightBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Thick);

            rightBorder.Color = "CC0000";

            tblBorders.AppendChild(rightBorder);



            LeftBorder leftBorder = new LeftBorder();

            leftBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Thick);

            leftBorder.Color = "CC0000";

            tblBorders.AppendChild(leftBorder);



            InsideHorizontalBorder insideHBorder = new InsideHorizontalBorder();

            insideHBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Thick);

            insideHBorder.Color = "CC0000";

            tblBorders.AppendChild(insideHBorder);



            InsideVerticalBorder insideVBorder = new InsideVerticalBorder();

            insideVBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Thick);

            insideVBorder.Color = "CC0000";

            tblBorders.AppendChild(insideVBorder);



            //// Add the table borders to the properties

            tableProp.AppendChild(tblBorders);

            // Apply
            tableProp.Append(tableStyle, tableWidth);

            return tableProp;

        }

        public static TableRow templaterow()
        {
            // Create 1 row to the table.
            TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();

            // Add a cell to each column in the row.
            TableCell tc1 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Step"))));
            TableCellProperties tcr1 = new TableCellProperties();

            var shading = new Shading()
            {
                Color = "auto",
                Fill = "B4C6E7",
                Val = ShadingPatternValues.Clear
            };
            tcr1.Append(shading);
            tc1.Append(tcr1);

            TableCell tc2 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("SubStep"))));
            TableCell tc3 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Group"))));
            TableCell tc4 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Description"))));
            TableCell tc5 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("ScreenShot"))));
            TableCellProperties tcr2 = new TableCellProperties();
            var shading2 = new Shading()
            {
                Color = "auto",
                Fill = "B4C6E7",
                Val = ShadingPatternValues.Clear
            };
            tcr2.Append(shading2);
            tc2.Append(tcr2);
            //tc2.Append(tcr1);

            tr1.Append(tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4, tc5);
            //tr1.Append(shading);
            return tr1;
        }

        public static TableRow rowcolumns(List<string> items)
        {
            // Create 1 row to the table.
            TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();
            for (var i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Amount is {0} and type is {1}", myMoney[i].amount, myMoney[i].type);
                //TableCell tc1 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(items[i]))));
                tr1.Append(cellcreaction(items[i]));
            }
            // Add a cell to each column in the row.
            //TableCell tc1 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Step"))));
            //TableCell tc2 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("SubStep"))));
            //TableCell tc3 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Group"))));
            //TableCell tc4 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Description"))));
            //TableCell tc5 = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("ScreenShot"))));
            //tr1.Append(tc1, tc2, tc3, tc4, tc5);

            return tr1;
        }

        public static TableCell cellcreaction(string txt)
        {
            return new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(txt))));
        }

        public static Paragraph paragraph(string txt)
        {
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
            Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
            run.AppendChild(new Text(txt));
            return para;

        }

        public static void InsertAPicture(string document, string fileName)
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument =
                WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;

                ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);

                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    imagePart.FeedData(stream);
                }

                AddImageToBody(wordprocessingDocument, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));
            }
        }

        private static void AddImageToBody(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, string relationshipId)
        {
            // Define the reference of the image.
            var element =
                 new Drawing(
                     new DW.Inline(
                         new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
                         new DW.EffectExtent()
                         {
                             LeftEdge = 0L,
                             TopEdge = 0L,
                             RightEdge = 0L,
                             BottomEdge = 0L
                         },
                         new DW.DocProperties()
                         {
                             Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                             Name = "Picture 1"
                         },
                         new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                             new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                         new A.Graphic(
                             new A.GraphicData(
                                 new PIC.Picture(
                                     new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                         new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                         {
                                             Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                             Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"
                                         },
                                         new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                                     new PIC.BlipFill(
                                         new A.Blip(
                                             new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                                 new A.BlipExtension()
                                                 {
                                                     Uri =
                                                        "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                                 })
                                         )
                                         {
                                             Embed = relationshipId,
                                             CompressionState =
                                             A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                         },
                                         new A.Stretch(
                                             new A.FillRectangle())),
                                     new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                         new A.Transform2D(
                                             new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                             new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                                         new A.PresetGeometry(
                                             new A.AdjustValueList()
                                         )
                                         { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                             )
                             { Uri = "https://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
                     )
                     {
                         DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                         DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                         DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                         DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
                         //EditId = "50D07946"
                     });

            // Append the reference to body, the element should be in a Run.
            wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(element)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and it took me longer than I'd like to find the answer as every example code for making tables I found had this issue. So I thought I'd post my solution here:

```
ParagraphProperties pProp = new ParagraphProperties();
SpacingBetweenLines spacing = new SpacingBetweenLines() { Line = "240", LineRule = LineSpacingRuleValues.Auto, Before = "0", After = "0" };
pProp.Append(spacing);

Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(cellText)));
p.PrependChild<ParagraphProperties>(pProp);

TableCell tc = new TableCell();
tc.Append(p);
```

Don't ask me what the Line = "240" bit means. It might not be needed, but the whole problem is table cells have paragraphs in them and paragraphs have space below them by default.  Get rid of that with the SpacingBetweenLines class.